# How to find difference in file size returned from C# web api to ajax success data

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, blob

I have a web api that sends an excel file as a response to ajax call. I added debug statements and looks like the size of the file that is returned as a response is 4 KB. When I check size of result in the success function, it shows as 7 KB. This is causing the excel file to corrupt and I'm unable to open it.

I have tried adding arraybuffer and blob in the response type but no luck.

```
Controller code:

[HttpGet]
public FileResult GetExcelFile(string parameters)
{
      byte[] contents = generateContents(parameters);

      return File(contents, "application/octet-stream", "Test.xlsx");
}


Ajax call:

$.ajax({
            url: webMethod,
            type: "GET",
            data: jQuery.param(parameters),
            success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                var filename = "";
                var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                    var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                    var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                    if (matches != null && matches[1]) {
                        filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
                    }
                }

                var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');

                var blob = new Blob([result], {type: type });
                console.log("Blob size: " + blob.size);
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = filename;
                link.click();
            }
        });
```

I don't know how extra data is added to the result in ajax success call. Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: In which form are you receiving the excel file? Is it FromBase64String?

Comment: Contents of an excel file is in byte array. `byte[] contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Test\\Testing.xlsx");`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. I hope it will help you.

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Create("C:/Test/Testing.xlsx"))
{
    stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
}
```

Comment: Apologies if my question is not clear. I'm generating contents an excel file and converting it as a byte[]. Then I'm creating a File object with byte[], content type and filename. `File(contents, "application/octet-stream", "Test.xlsx");`.  I verified that File object size is as 4 KB. But when I try to access the data on ajax call, it shows that the size is 7 KB.  This additional data is causing issues in excel file

Answer (score 0):

You can test to just redirect to the url of the webmethod. If you just want to get it to work.

```c#
// Get excel file
// GET: /home/getexcelfile
[HttpGet]
public FileResult GetExcelFile(string parameters)
{
    byte[] contents = generateContents(parameters);

    return File(contents, "application/octet-stream", "Test.xlsx");
}
```

```js
<input type="button" onclick="download()" value="Download Excel-file" />
function download() 
{
    // GetExcelFile
    location.href = '/home/getexcelfile?parameters=bbbdhddhhdhdh'; 
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me on how to use in the above ajax call?

Comment: You do not need to make an ajax call, just a simple get request. Se my updated answer.